# What's the difference between asio::io_context and asio::thread_pool?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, asio

Whats the difference between an `asio::thread_pool` and an `asio::io_context` whose `run()` function is called from multiple threads? Can I replace my `boost::thread_group` of threads that call `io_context::run()` with an `asio::thread_pool`? Or do I need somewhere an `io_context`?

**Update**

When I use `asio::thread_pool`, do I still need an `io_context` to use sockets, timers, etc? Both `thread_pool` and `io_context` are an `asio::execution_context`. However, the docs say on `io_context` that it "Provides core I/O functionality". Do I lose these if I only use an `asio::thread_pool` without an `io_context`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A threadpool implicit runs all the tasks posted on it (until it's stopped).

An io_service doesn't assume anything about the threads that will run it: you need to make sure you do that, and you're free to decide whether you run it on multiple threads, one thread, or even a mix (like one thread at at time, but from multiple threads?).

Further notes:

- handle exceptions emanating from `io_service` run/poll members ([Should the exception thrown by boost::asio::io_service::run() be caught?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500818/should-the-exception-thrown-by-boostasioio-servicerun-be-caught/44500924#44500924))
- if you run an io_service on multiple threads, make sure you understand thread-safety of the service objects you use (see [Why do I need strand per connection when using boost::asio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794107/why-do-i-need-strand-per-connection-when-using-boostasio/12801042#12801042))
- If you know how many threads will run your service, consider supplying the concurrency hint on construction (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/concurrency_hint.html)
- `io_service` can be restarted (after a `reset()`). `asio::thread_pool` not so much (see [search is [dead atm](https://twitter.com/sehetw/status/1262462113018253314)], compare with [asio::io_service and thread_group lifecycle issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34304286/asioio-service-and-thread-group-lifecycle-issue/34306588#34306588))
- The threads governed by `asio::thread_pool` are "opaque": you cannot control how they're created. Which is a bummer if you need to e.g. initialize a third party library per thread or wanted to use Boost Thread with [`interruption_point`s](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.interruption) etc.

Comment: Excellent points and links, thanks! I'll consider these. One thing is still unclear to me (I've updated the question): Do I need an io_service to use sockets and timers? Or does the thread_pool provide the same functionalities?

Comment: @ValarMorghulis Both `io_context` and `thread_pool` are perfectly capable [`execution_context`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/execution_context.html) instances. In fact, for specific services using only one execution context could be more efficient than multiple. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33529876/85371 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055496/are-multiple-asio-io-services-a-good-thing

Comment: You can control how threads are created and then attached to a thread_pool. Initialize an empty pool by calling the thread_pool constructor with integer argument and passing 0. Then create your threads and call the thread_pool.attach() method. Simplest example: auto* t = new std::thread([](){pool.attach()});

Comment: @muusbolla Do not use `new` there (consider maybe `detach()` instead). Also, that's not full control: It's merely the option to _grow_, never shrink. That could be very important if your threads need thread-local initializations (like `mysql_thread_init`, or your own singleton instances)